# Why is the axis color cycle reduced to a single color when setting some other property cycle?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In python/matplotlib:

When I set the "marker" property cycle (for example), the color cycle just yields a constant (blue) color. See example below.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2)

ax1.set_prop_cycle(marker=['o','s','x','+','*'])

xx = np.arange(10)
for n in xx:
  ax1.plot(xx, n*xx)
  ax2.plot(xx, n*xx)

plt.show()
```

Result:
[image: screenshot]

How can I get the color cycle to *remain* what it was, as in the 2nd axis?

Answer (score 3):

The property cycler can comprise of different properties, such as color, maker, linestyle etc. When setting the property cycler via `ax1.set_prop_cycle(marker=[...])` you create a new property cycler which only contains a marker property, but no color.

In order to have a marker **and** color property you either need to set both, or extent the current property cycler by the property you want to change. The latter would be shown in the following.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2)

cycler = plt.rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"]
cycler += plt.cycler(marker=['o','s','x','+','*'])
ax1.set_prop_cycle(cycler)


colors = plt.rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"].by_key()["color"]
cycler2 = plt.cycler(color=colors)
cycler2 *= plt.cycler(marker=['o','s','x','+','*'])
ax2.set_prop_cycle(cycler2)

xx = np.arange(10)
for n in xx:
  ax1.plot(xx, n*xx)
  ax2.plot(xx, n*xx)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note the difference between addition and multiplication here.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the `color_cycle` using `rcParams` and assign them as the colors for `ax1` as (`matplotlib` version `2.0.2`)

```
 ax1.set_prop_cycle(marker=['o','s','x','+','*'], color=plt.rcParams['axes.color_cycle'])
```

The colors might be different on your machine but will be consistent in both the plots.

EDIT (@ImportanceOfBeingEarnest's suggestion in the comments) in case of depreciation warning

```
ax1.set_prop_cycle(marker=['o','s','x','+','*'], color=plt.rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"].by_key()["color"][:5])
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain his/her downvote. Downvoting without any comment is just unjustified.

Comment: That method is actually more compact than the one in my answer. So I guess that was just some random downvote that sometimes happens on SO.

Comment: Thanks. This is probably the solution. Howver, the cyclers (markers/colors) need to be of the same length (seems they coincidentally are in your case, but not in mine, yielding an error). Ideally, I would have liked to avoid this. Also, axes.color_cycle yields deprecation warning in favour of axes.prop_cycle, but the latter does not support slicing (to get the correct length).

Comment: No, but it makes sense if someone sees the use of a deprecated method or a solution which only works in an old version.

Comment: What would work though is `ax1.set_prop_cycle(marker=['o','s','x','+','*'], color=plt.rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"].by_key()["color"][:5])`. Maybe @Bazingaa can update their answer with that.

Comment: Oh yes, I have both versions installed on my Mac and I happen to find this solution in version `2.0.2`. I have edited your suggestion in my answer. Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest